# Is it possible to define an arbitrarily, highly nested array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

In JavaScript, we can flexibly define arbitrarily, highly nested arrays. For example, the following.

```
var arr1 = [ [0, 1], [2, 3] ];
var arr2 = [ 
 [ [0, 1], [2, 3] ], 
 [ [4, 5], [6, 7] ] 
];
```

Is it possible to define something like this in Java for a field of a class? The field must be able to store arbitrary dimensions/depths of nested arrays.

I was thinking about using a List of Lists.

```
List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, this is in some sense, only a 2D matrix. Note that the index is significant (it has meaning) for my use case.

I suppose I can also create a Tree structure, but that might require some non-trivial work to get it right.

```
public class Node {
 int index; //like the index of an array i want, unique amongst nodes of same level sharing a common parent
 List<Integer> values; //the actual elements, if any
 List<Node> children; //nesting deeper
}
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Are you after the `var` syntax? You'll have to declare its type explicitly, with the appropriate "dimensions", `Object[]`, `Object[][]`, `Object[][][]`, etc. depending on what you need.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Object` for the variable declaration, but then you'll need a bunch of casts anyway to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Yes, the `private Object arr;` field approach has occurred to me. It seems very easy to work with, but that would require type casting and checking, and it might appear the approach is a kludge rather than a disciplined one.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @chrylis At an implementation level, to mimic the nested array in Java as I have already done for JavaScript. At a high level, these nested arrays and their indices represent state transitions from and to probabilities. If I can get away with doing something like this nested array in Java, my code from JavaScript to Java is 90% copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strongly typed language, you define the dimensionality of the array when you declare it. Like,

```
int[][] arr1 = { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } };
int[][][] arr2 = { { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } }, { { 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 } } };
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2));
```

However, it is also possible to make an `Object` refer to any array (because arrays are `Object` instances). In the example above, note the signature is [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-).

Comment: Yes, all those points are understood. However, this `nested array` (for the use of a better term) will be declared as a field in a class and must be able to store an arbitrary depth of nested array, that are not known a priori. The dimensions are determined outside.

Comment: @JaneWayne Then you'll need to use `Object`, and you can use the methods in [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can do something like this (if it makes sense for you):

```
List<List<List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

2) Also as Javascript, Java can have multi dimensional arrays

```
Integer[][] arr = {{1,2},{2,3}};
```

3) To create an Array in runtime, you can use reflection:

```
Integer[] array = (Integer[])Array.newInstance(Integer.class, d1);
Integer[][] array = (Integer[][])Array.newInstance(Integer.class, d1, d2);
Integer[][][] array = (Integer[][][])Array.newInstance(Integer.class, d1, d2, d3);
```

[newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29)

4) Also you can use a library that implements multi dimensional array. Like:

[Vectorz](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz)

I think the last option is the best one in your case.

Comment: That does make sense, except for that the depth of the nesting can be different for each instance, and is not known a priori. Unless, we can use reflection or some other technique to dynamically declare the dimensions once they are determined?

Comment: sure you can create dynamically multi dimensional array with reflection, but I think it is to complicated and it is easier to use a library